# How to retrieve pool adresses

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, rpc, jsonrpc-api

My goal is to obtain pool addresses associated with a given mint address. I'm looking for a method or approach that would allow me to efficiently fetch this data.
To clarify i dont want to download the whole mainnet from example raydium api.

I understand that pool addresses are crucial for interacting with liquidity pools and for performing operations like swaps, but I'm not sure how to reverse-engineer or lookup pool addresses starting from mint addresses directly. Specifically, I'm interested in:

Any existing RPC calls, Solana Web3.js functions, or third-party APIs that facilitate this lookup.
Best practices in handling such queries to ensure efficiency and minimize the impact on network resources.
Potential pitfalls or considerations to keep in mind when implementing this feature.